# find last child in recursive function

Tags: php, mysql

[recursive function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXjcg.jpg)

im trying to achieve above condition.

i have successful list parent and multi-level child title in **tab title section**

Now in **Tab Content** im trying to list content for the title listed in **Tab title**
In Tab Content if parent have multi-level child then only last child content should display but if parent does have any child then parent content should display

But im getting content for all title parent as well as nested child here i want last child content  only but if parent does have child then parent content should be displayed

how to check if parent have any child, if parent have child then display content for last child only, if parent doesn’t have child then display parent content

**Code for displaying Multi-level-nested child Title in Tab Title**

```
$categoryMulti = array(
'categories' => array(),
'parent_cats' => array()
);   

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name`, `content` FROM categories";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $categoryMulti['categories'][$row['id']] = $row;
    $categoryMulti['parent_cats'][$row['parent_id']][] = $row['id'];
}


//title for tabs
function listCategoryTree($parent, $category)
{
    $css_class = ($parent == 0 ? "parent" : "child");   
    
    $html = '';
    if (isset($category['parent_cats'][$parent])) {
        $html .= '<ul class="im-'.$css_class.'">'."\n";
        foreach ($category['parent_cats'][$parent] as $cat_id) {
            if (!isset($category['parent_cats'][$cat_id])) {
                $html .= '<li id="">
                <a href="" data-cap= "'.$css_class.'-'.$cat_id.'">'
                 . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['name'] . 
                 '</a>';
                 '</li>'."\r";
            } else {
                $html .= '<li id="">
                 <a href="" data-cap= "'.$css_class.'-'.$cat_id.'">'


                . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['name'] . 

                '</a> <span>arrow icon </span>'."\r";
                $html .= listCategoryTree($cat_id, $category);
                $html .= '</li>'."\r";
            }
        }
        $html .= '</ul>'."\n";
    }
    return $html;
}
```

**Code trying to display last child content if parent have multi-level-nested child and if parent does have any child display parent content**
but its display content for all nested-child and parent content too.

```
//content for tabs
$contentTab = array(
    'contentCat' => array(),
    'contentChild' => array()
);   
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `parent_id`, `name`, `content` FROM categories";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $contentTab['contentCat'][$row['id']] = $row;
    $contentTab['contentChild'][$row['parent_id']][] = $row['id'];
}

function listContentTree($parent, $category)
{
    $css_class = ($parent == 0 ? "parent" : "child");   
    
    $html = '';
    if (isset($category['contentChild'][$parent])) {
        $html .= '<ul class="im-'.$css_class.'">'."\n";
        foreach ($category['contentChild'][$parent] as $cat_id) {
            if (!isset($category['contentChild'][$cat_id])) {
                $html .= '<li id="'.$css_class.'-'.$cat_id.'">
                <a href="" data-cap= "">im child content test---'
                 . $category['contentCat'][$cat_id]['content'] . 
                 '</a>';
                 '</li>'."\r";
            } else {
                $html .= '<li id="'.$css_class.'-'.$cat_id.'">
                 <a href="" data-cap= "">hello parent test------'


                . $category['contentCat'][$cat_id]['content'] . 

                '</a>'."\r";
                $html .= listContentTree($cat_id, $category);
                $html .= '</li>'."\r";
            }
        }
        $html .= '</ul>'."\n";
    }
    return $html;
}
```

how check to for last child.

```
if(has last child){
  then display content of last child
}else{
//where parent doesnt have any child
  display content of parent
}
```